# C++ Storing rows as part of a 2D array and then printing a row

Tags: c++, arrays

The objective is to print symbols in a 5 by 5 grid, with `$` being printed (space after) if the value is 1 and `%` if the value is 0.

Each row is an array of 5 integers, all of which are 0 or 1.

It says to initialize the first, or 0th row:

```
int row0[0] = {1,0,0,0,1};
```

It then says to store the rows themselves in a 2D array:

```
int twodim[5][5]; 

twodim[0] = {1,0,0,0,1};
```

The above is confusing because we are supposed to print a whole row and are passed in 2 arguments, const int row[], and size. Size is 5. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to print the whole row because no column is passed in (I'm not sure it matters or if I am misunderstanding the concept. Basically I'm not sure how to access a whole row in the above case.

Any hints that might help me get started?

Comment: Sounds too much like homework for me to tell you what to do here. But you should definitely look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ for printing, and range based for loops http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html for a nice clean answer. Now as far as the parameters... you're gonna have to give more information or talk to the person who gave the assignment.

Comment: I've reversed your last edit. Once people have begun to post answers to your question, it's not appropriate to then remove all of the content. If you'd like to ask for it to be deleted entirely, click the `flag` link right below the tags, and ask the moderators to do so. Removing the content makes the answers meaningless, and wastes the time of those people who read your question and wrote answers. Thanks.

Comment: If you're printing a row, you have to print each column, therefore no column index is needed as an argument. You have to print all columns you get in a row[], you already know how many of them is there with `size`.

Answer (score 4):

Take care: `2dim` is not a valid identifier in C++ because it starts with a numeric character.
To display a two dimensional array like you explained, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int dim[5][5] = {
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
   };

   for (size_t x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      for (size_t y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
         std::cout << (dim[x][y] == 0 ? '%' : '$') << ' ';
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```